# How to increase Android FTrace precision to microseconds?

Tags: android, linux, ftrace, systrace

I'm trying to generate **FTrace** files inside an **Android** environment, using:

```
root@adroid:# echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/sched/sched_switch/enable
root@adroid:# echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_on
root@adroid:# cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace > mytracefile.txt
root@adroid:# echo 0 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_on
root@adroid:# echo 0 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/sched/sched_switch/enable
```

The problem is that in **mytracefile.txt** the precision of time stamp is in **milliseconds**:

```
          <idle>-0     [000] d.h7 14186.690000: sched_wakeup: comm=tfm_b6bcf800 pid=1714 prio=35 success=1 target_cpu=000
          <idle>-0     [000] d..3 14186.690000: sched_switch: prev_comm=swapper/0 prev_pid=0 prev_prio=120 prev_state=R ==> next_comm=tfm_b6bcf800 next_pid=1714 next_prio=35
    tfm_b6bcf800-1714  [000] d..3 14186.690000: sched_switch: prev_comm=tfm_b6bcf800 prev_pid=1714 prev_prio=35 prev_state=D|W ==> next_comm=swapper/0 next_pid=0 next_prio=120
          <idle>-0     [001] d.h3 14186.690000: sched_wakeup: comm=Player Aud Mixe pid=146 prio=35 success=1 target_cpu=001
          <idle>-0     [001] d..3 14186.690000: sched_switch: prev_comm=swapper/1 prev_pid=0 prev_prio=120 prev_state=R ==> next_comm=Player Aud Mixe next_pid=146 next_prio=35
 Player Aud Mixe-146   [001] d..3 14186.690000: sched_switch: prev_comm=Player Aud Mixe prev_pid=146 prev_prio=35 prev_state=D ==> next_comm=swapper/1 next_pid=0 next_prio=120
          <idle>-0     [001] d.h3 14186.690000: sched_wakeup: comm=Player Aud Mixe pid=146 prio=35 success=1 target_cpu=001
          <idle>-0     [001] d..3 14186.690000: sched_switch: prev_comm=swapper/1 prev_pid=0 prev_prio=120 prev_state=R ==> next_comm=Player Aud Mixe next_pid=146 next_prio=35
 Player Aud Mixe-146   [001] d..3 14186.690000: sched_switch: prev_comm=Player Aud Mixe prev_pid=146 prev_prio=35 prev_state=S ==> next_comm=swapper/1 next_pid=0 next_prio=120
          <idle>-0     [001] d.h3 14186.700000: sched_wakeup: comm=Player Aud Mixe pid=146 prio=35 success=1 target_cpu=001
          <idle>-0     [001] d..3 14186.700000: sched_switch: prev_comm=swapper/1 prev_pid=0 prev_prio=120 prev_state=R ==> next_comm=Player Aud Mixe next_pid=146 next_prio=35
```

Normally, it should be in the order of **microseconds**, like **14186.691234** instead of just **14186.690000**.

I have already tested all the other **trace_clock options** that I have (**local, global and counter**) but the results are always the same. Changing that parameter doesn't change anything in the output file.

I followed carefully [FTrace documentation](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt) but I don't know what else to change in configuration.

Searching over the internet I had only been able to find this bug report but it was not solved: http://lists.linaro.org/pipermail/linaro-dev/2011-February/002720.html

Any advises?

Are there additional modules in the kernel that I have to install ?

**Update:**

- Android Version: 4.2.2
- Kernel Linux Version: 3.4.7

**dmesg** output is also showing milliseconds precision:

```
<4>[   38.130000] oom_adj 0 => oom_score_adj 0
<4>[   38.130000] oom_adj 1 => oom_score_adj 58
<4>[   38.140000] oom_adj 2 => oom_score_adj 117
<4>[   38.140000] oom_adj 4 => oom_score_adj 235
<4>[   38.150000] oom_adj 9 => oom_score_adj 529
<4>[   38.150000] oom_adj 15 => oom_score_adj 1000
```

Thank you,

Comment: You need to look at the kernel version that you are using on your android device. Probably checking that kernel source would be helpful.

Comment: @rakib Thank you, I added the kernel version and did some updates to the question.

Comment: Well, what I was saying is look for the Android kernel you're using. You need to look at that Android kernel's ftrace feature, whether was there any modification in ftrace code or so. Generally Android kernel contains some modification from stable Linux kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a nanosecond accurate timer in Android.  Milliseconds is the best you can get.

Comment: Sorry, I made an update to the question. I'm interested in **microseconds**, I'm sure that we can get that precision because it is explicitly shown in FTrace documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all hardware have the ability to generate millisecond-accurate times, but the accuracy of timers is hardware dependent. Many system these days offer timers with microsecond or better resolution. These can usually be configured to provide the precision you want.